# react can't display random listing using aggregate when i click reload

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, math

I am creating a website recipes.In that I need to display the recipes in random order only i click reload.in my code i don't what's wrong it only showing no recipe is found.And i agin saying i need random only the page reload.

this is routes

```
router.get("/", async (req ,res ) => {
    const seed = req.query.seed || Math.random();

    try{
        const response = await RecipeModel.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 10, seed } }])
        res.json(response);
    } catch(err) {
        res.json(err);

    }
});
```

In my navbar

```
  <Link to={`/createrecipe?seed=${Date.now()}`} className="recipes">
        Recipes
      </Link>
```

this is recipe page

```
export const Recipes = () => {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecipes = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/recipes");
        setRecipes(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchRecipes();
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="create-container">
      <div className="create-box">
        <span>Recipes</span>
        {recipes.length > 0 ? (
          recipes.map((recipe) => (
            <Card className="create-card" key={recipe._id}>
              <Card.Img className="create-img" variant="top" src={recipe.imageUrl} alt={recipe.title} />
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Subtitle className="create-category">
                  <MDBIcon className="create-bell" fas icon="concierge-bell" />
                  {recipe.category}
                </Card.Subtitle>
                <Card.Title>{recipe.title}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>{recipe.description}</Card.Text>
                <Link to={`/createrecipe/${recipe._id}`} className="view-recipe">View Recipe</Link>
                <Button >Save</Button>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          ))
        ) : (
          <div>No recipes found.</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I need to display recipe in random order only when the page is reload.

Comment: I think you forgot to include your code

Answer (score 0):

There is no seed option in [sample](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) aggregation. You should remove seed.

```
  const response = await RecipeModel.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 10} }]);
```